# Actionbar keeps hiding

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I'm currently trying to build an Android app with Xamarin Studio (aka monodroid). My problem is as follows: 
In my Activity's `OnCreate` I call

```cs
this.RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBar);
this.RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionModeOverlay);
```

Also, I added this override to the Activity:

```cs
public override Boolean OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    if (this.ActionBar.IsShowing)
    {
        this.ActionBar.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        this.ActionBar.Show();
    }

    return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
}
```

This, however, doesn't work as I expect it to: When I first tap on the Activity, the bar is hidden. The next tap shows it, but it doesn't even fully slide into view before it retreats again. Also, it seems to "cram" the contents of the Activity, which it shouldn't do since I added `WindowFeatures.ActionModeOverlay`.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**
I am certain that the method itself is only triggered once per touch (I logged a counter to diagnose).
Also, I don't `show()`/`hide()` the ActionBar anywhere else.

**EDIT 2:** I *was* certain, but probably messed up the diagnostic approach. :/ 
After adding

```cs
if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Cancel
    || e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
{
    return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
}
```

it behaves as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Motion Event is catching an event when you are releasing a touch, you need to filter the event further using `e.Action` for touch down and release events. I think down is triggering show, and release is hiding it again

Comment: I'm not sure we're having the same thing in mind. The Actionbar is __not__ what e.g. the Nexus devices have instead of hardware buttons. It's the thing that sits below the title bar (in apps that use the holo themes).

Comment: Happens! Got any advice on the other Actionbar?

Comment: I actually logged a counter in that method, it is called once per touch.

Comment: My bad-- I edited the question. If you edit your answer with your suggestion in the comment, I'll give you the credit.